# Flutter: how get all properties for all widgets's objects in my flutter app by dart Code to use it in Test?

Tags: flutter, dart, testing

**Flutter:** how get all properties for all widgets's objects in my flutter app by dart Code to use it in **Automated Testing** ?
I know exist three types from testing :

**1. Unit tests.

2. Widget tests. 

3. Integration tests.**

---

But I just want to know all the details about each Widget and also Write it in a text file?
for Example [this image explain an example in Dev tool But I neet it by codeing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95dYL.png)

*Thanks in advance*

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by "details"? Widget state? Widget location? Widget runtime type?

Comment: Thank you, I mean widget properties 
Ex: widget  "FloatingActionButton" I need to know Text, tooltip, actions and etc. for it .

Comment: i uploaded image in post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your tests you could use this code to access the properties of a widget in the current tree:

```
final FloatingActionButton fab = tester.widget(find.byType(FloatingActionButton));

expect(fab.tooltip, ...);
```

Here you tell the WidgetTester to find a widget in the current widget tree, when a widget is found you can access its properties.

Important, that your 'First A, Arrange' is correctly setup, thus a widget tree is build and the widget you're looking for is available.

When you are searching for a more generic widget which occures more then once in the widget tree I suggest using the find.byKey method, like so:

```
tester.widget(find.byKey(Key('exampleKey')));
```

Ofcourse, the Finder widget has more than two methods, thus any of the other find methods could be used.

Greetz

Comment: thanks a lot,
I'm already accessing the item but I don't know how to access the properties?

Comment: Please , How get unique ID of each Widget?

Comment: Take a look at this page of the flutter cookbook:

https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/testing/widget/finders

You can add a key to your widget in code, then in your test you can use the same key to find the relevant widget.

Comment: I know this , but the key property Don't help me for all cases. Because I will be testing a code that I am not a writer, and it may contain widgets that do not have key.

Comment: In that case, you should use another find method. By type for example. Ideally the person who writes a widget or a set of widgets for your app should also writes the tests for that widget. When all widget or set of widgets can be tested individually, (using Widget test) and all functionality can be tested indivdually (using unit tests), then integration or golden tests can be written.